# Using variable in expression with Nullif fails

Tags: variables, pyspark, expr, nullif

I'm using the code below to convert an empty string to Null.
I don't get an error but it remains an empty string.
I suspect an incorrect use of the variable `col_name` in `expr`

```
for col_name in ['col1', 'col2']:
    df_new = df \
        .withColumn(col_name, F.expr(f"nullif('{col_name}', '')"))
```

Comment: `f"nullif({col_name}, '')"`

Comment: I get an error `col should be Column`  `.withColumn(col_name, f"nullif({col_name}, '')")`

Comment: please show complete code and error

Comment: oh I mean `F.expr(f"nullif({col_name}, '')")`

Comment: but the dataframe will not be updated using your code, see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is this. Be aware that the for-loop will create and overwrite `df_new`, so the final column only be changed.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_new = df
for col_name in ['col1', 'col2']:
    df_new = df_new.withColumn(col_name, f.expr(f"nullif({col_name}, '')"))
```